# C memory management virtual Machine oversized output

Tags: c, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently working on a virtual machine implementation in C as a hobby project. Although I have experience in C programming, I am still a beginner in memory management. I am facing an issue with my code and I need help to resolve it.

The error message that I am getting is "44184 bytes, 215.74% oversized." This error is related to the memory management of my virtual machine implementation. I am not sure what is causing this error and how to fix it.

44184 bytes, 215.74% oversized

**--the code is --**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_START 0x0000
#define INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_END 0x03ff
#define DATA_MEMORY_START 0x0400
#define DATA_MEMORY_END 0x07ff
#define VIRTUAL_ROUTINES_START 0x0800
#define VIRTUAL_ROUTINES_END 0x08ff
#define HEAP_BANKS_START 0xb700
#define INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_SIZE (INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_END - INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_START + 1)

#define REGISTER_COUNT 32

typedef struct {
    uint8_t memory[0x10000]; // 2^16 bytes of memory
    uint32_t registers[REGISTER_COUNT];
    uint32_t pc;
} RISKXVII_VM;

typedef enum {
    R_TYPE = 0,
    I_TYPE,
    S_TYPE,
    SB_TYPE,
    U_TYPE,
    UJ_TYPE
} InstructionType;

typedef struct {
    InstructionType type;
    uint32_t opcode;
    uint32_t func3;
    uint32_t func7;
    uint32_t rd;
    uint32_t rs1;
    uint32_t rs2;
    int32_t imm;
} Instruction;
void init_vm(RISKXVII_VM *vm) {
    memset(vm->memory, 0, sizeof(vm->memory));
    memset(vm->registers, 0, sizeof(vm->registers));
    vm->pc = INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_START;
}

bool decode_instruction(uint32_t instruction_value, Instruction *instruction) {
   
    // Clear the instruction struct
    memset(instruction, 0, sizeof(Instruction));

    // Extract the fields from the instruction_value and populate the instruction struct
    instruction->opcode = instruction_value & 0b01111111;
    instruction->rd = (instruction_value >> 7) & 0b11111;
    instruction->func3 = (instruction_value >> 12) & 0b111;
    instruction->rs1 = (instruction_value >> 15) & 0b11111;
    instruction->rs2 = (instruction_value >> 20) & 0b11111;
    instruction->func7 = (instruction_value >> 25) & 0b1111111;

    // Determine the instruction type and populate the immediate field if necessary
    switch (instruction->opcode) {
        case 0b0110011:
            instruction->type = R_TYPE;
            break;
        case 0b0010011:
            instruction->type = I_TYPE;
            instruction->imm = (instruction_value >> 20) & 0b11111111111;
            break;
        // Add other cases for different opcodes
        default:
            printf("Unknown opcode: %08x\n", instruction->opcode);
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
bool execute_instruction(RISKXVII_VM *vm, Instruction *instruction) {
     uint32_t addr;
    uint32_t value;
    switch (instruction->type) {
        case R_TYPE:
            switch (instruction->opcode) {
                case 0b0110011: // R-Type opcode
                    switch (instruction->func3) {
                        case 0b000: // Add or Sub
                            if (instruction->func7 == 0b0000000) {
                                vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] + vm->registers[instruction->rs2]; // Add
                            } else if (instruction->func7 == 0b0100000) {
                                vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] - vm->registers[instruction->rs2]; // Sub
                            } else {
                                printf("Unknown func7: %08x\n", instruction->func7);
                                return false;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b001: // SLL
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] << vm->registers[instruction->rs2];
                            break;
                        case 0b100: // XOR
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] ^ vm->registers[instruction->rs2];
                            break;
                        case 0b101: // SRL or SRA
                            if (instruction->func7 == 0b0000000) {
                                vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] >> vm->registers[instruction->rs2]; // SRL
                            } else if (instruction->func7 == 0b0100000) {
                                vm->registers[instruction->rd] = (int32_t)vm->registers[instruction->rs1] >> vm->registers[instruction->rs2]; // SRA
                            } else {
                                printf("Unknown func7: %08x\n", instruction->func7);
                                return false;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b110: // OR
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] | vm->registers[instruction->rs2];
                            break;
                        case 0b111: // AND
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] & vm->registers[instruction->rs2];
                            break;
                        //Memory Access Instructions

                        default:
                            printf("Unknown func3: %08x\n", instruction->func3);
                            return false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Unknown R-Type opcode: %08x\n", instruction->opcode);
                    return false;
            }
            break;
       
        case S_TYPE:
            addr = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] + instruction->imm;
            switch (instruction->opcode) {
                case 0b0100011: // S-Type opcode
                    switch (instruction->func3) {
                        case 0b000: // sb
                            value = vm->registers[instruction->rs2] & 0xFF;
                            memcpy(vm->memory + addr, &value, 1);
                            break;
                        case 0b001: // sh
                            value = vm->registers[instruction->rs2] & 0xFFFF;
                            memcpy(vm->memory + addr, &value, 2);
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Unknown func3: %08x\n", instruction->func3);
                            return false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Unknown S-Type opcode: %08x\n", instruction->opcode);
                    return false;
            }
            break;

        case I_TYPE:
            addr = vm->registers[instruction->rs1] + instruction->imm;
            switch (instruction->opcode) {
                case 0b0000011: // I-Type opcode
                    switch (instruction->func3) {
                        // Add the cases for the load instructions
                        case 0b000: // lb
                            memcpy(&value, vm->memory + addr, 1);
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = (int32_t)(int8_t)value; // sign extend
                            break;
                        case 0b001: // lh
                            memcpy(&value, vm->memory + addr, 2);
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = (int32_t)(int16_t)value; // sign extend
                            break;
                        case 0b010: // lw
                            memcpy(&value, vm->memory + addr, 4);
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = value;
                            break;
                        case 0b100: // lbu
                            memcpy(&value, vm->memory + addr, 1);
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = value & 0xFF;
                            break;
                        case 0b101: // lhu
                            memcpy(&value, vm->memory + addr, 2);
                            vm->registers[instruction->rd] = value & 0xFFFF;
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Unknown func3: %08x\n", instruction->func3);
                            return false;
                    }
                    break;
                    
                // Other I-Type opcodes cases
                // ...
                default:
                    printf("Unknown I-Type opcode: %08x\n", instruction->opcode);
                    return false;
            }
            break;
        // Add cases for SB_TYPE, U_TYPE, and UJ_TYPE instructions
        case SB_TYPE:
            switch (instruction->opcode) {
                case 0b1100011: // SB-Type opcode
                    switch (instruction->func3) {
                        case 0b000: // beq
                            if (vm->registers[instruction->rs1] == vm->registers[instruction->rs2]) {
                                vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b001: // bne
                            if (vm->registers[instruction->rs1] != vm->registers[instruction->rs2]) {
                                vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b100: // blt
                            if ((int32_t)vm->registers[instruction->rs1] < (int32_t)vm->registers[instruction->rs2]) {
                                vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b110: // bltu
                            if (vm->registers[instruction->rs1] < vm->registers[instruction->rs2]) {
                                vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b101: // bge
                            if ((int32_t)vm->registers[instruction->rs1] >= (int32_t)vm->registers[instruction->rs2]) {
                                vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 0b111: // bgeu
                            if (vm->registers[instruction->rs1] >= vm->registers[instruction->rs2]) {
                                vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                                return true;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("Unknown func3: %08x\n", instruction->func3);
                            return false;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Unknown SB-Type opcode: %08x\n", instruction->opcode);
                    return false;
            }
            break;

        case UJ_TYPE:
            switch (instruction->opcode) {
                case 0b1101111: // jal
                    vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->pc + 4;
                    vm->pc += instruction->imm << 1;
                    return true;
                    break;

                case 0b1100111: // jalr
                    vm->registers[instruction->rd] = vm->pc + 4;
                    vm->pc = (vm->registers[instruction->rs1] + instruction->imm) & ~1;
                    return true;
                    break;

                
                default:
                    printf("Unknown UJ-Type opcode: %08x\n", instruction->opcode);
                    return false;
            }
            break;

        default:
            printf("Unknown instruction type: %d\n", instruction->type);
            return false;
    }


    // Increment the program counter
    vm->pc += 4;

    return true;

    
}
bool run_vm(RISKXVII_VM *vm) {
    while (vm->pc >= INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_START && vm->pc <= INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_END) {
        uint32_t instruction_value = *(uint32_t *) (vm->memory + vm->pc);
        Instruction instruction;

        if (!decode_instruction(instruction_value, &instruction)) {
            printf("Failed to decode instruction at address: %08x\n", vm->pc);
            return false;
        }

        if (!execute_instruction(vm, &instruction)) {
            printf("Failed to execute instruction at address: %08x\n", vm->pc);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <path_to_binary>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    RISKXVII_VM vm;
    init_vm(&vm);

    // Read the binary file into the
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    if (file_size > INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_SIZE) {
        printf("Binary file too large for instruction memory.\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fread(vm.memory + INSTRUCTION_MEMORY_START, 1, file_size, file) != file_size) {
        perror("Error reading binary file");
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(file);
    if (run_vm(&vm)) {
        printf("Program execution finished successfully.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Program execution failed.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're probably trashing the heap somewhere by writing outside an allocated block of memory. Put range checks on all your writes to any buffer and see if you can get a breakpoint in your debugger.

Comment: You do not show any allocating or freeing of dynamic memory in your code. Where do you get the mentioned error message?

Comment: Maybe you are compiling it with a stack size (warning).

Comment: i have a script to validate the heap its a challenge offered somewhere and the code is tested on the server side

Comment: I wonder if you move  line 311  "RISKXVII_VM vm;"  outside the main() to global, if it would resolve the issue.